# Entity Framework - How to prevent a model property from column creation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Folks,

I am developing an web application based on ASP .NET MVC 4.

Let's say I define a model such as:

```
public class MyUser {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

}

The database initializer code will automatically create a table with three columns - UserName, FirstName, and LastName.

However, let's say I don't want LastName to be part of the database table.

Is there any data annotation attribute that I can use to prevent a property from being exposed as a column?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use NotMapped attribute. Here is a very [good reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591583) about different attribute you can use.

```
public class MyUser {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```